# Как у даты установить таймзону?

Tags: python

Есть переменная типа дата.

```
testdate = datetime.today()
2023-01-02 22:30:34.140101
```

А надо с таймзоной

```
2023-01-02 22:30:34.140101+00:00
```

Как у даты установить таймзону, при этом не надо никуда смещать время, просто поменять формат?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `datetime` уже всё есть. Подробнее изучить эту тему можно [тут](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). Так же можете поискать `datetime.timezone`

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now()
print(date.astimezone()) #2023-01-02 23:02:52.837047+03:00
```

Comment: Оказывается тип должен быть datetime.datetime, для datetime.date не будет таймзоны.